# Can a 1.3W rated SOT23 MOSFET deal with 0.9 W peaks?

Tags: power, mosfet, surface-mount

I have a TL431 LDO voltage regulator that uses a tiny P MOSFET in a SOT23 case rated at maximum 1.3W (IRLML6401TRPBF). Can it handle 0.9W bursts of 1 second every 10 seconds without a heatsink?

I would put multiple MOSFETs in parallel but current won't be distributed evenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two in parallel - they will current-share because as a MOSFET heats up its on resistance also rises (unlike bipolar transistors). Also mount them with some decent copper on the PCB.

Below are some relevant facts from the data sheet: -

[image]

On the upper graph I've cheekily modified the safe operating area and this basically tells me that for a 1 second pulse the limit is somewhere around 0.9W (which is your limit).

The middle table tells me that the junction of the device will warm up about 100ºC for 1W being dissipated and this reminds about point (3) and the amount of copper around the device that restricts this to **only** 100ºC.

The lower picture tells me that whatever the duty cycle is, a 1 second pulse might as well be infinitely long - the thermal response will be virtually 100% over a period of 1 second.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, so 2 MOSFETs in parallel will balance the current as they heat up.

Comment: They will and I might even consider using three

Comment: @Andy aka When I recall it right you can parallel MOSFETs only for switching applications NOT as a linear element. The gate threshold is lower for the warmer MOSFET so they are drifting apart until one blows up.

Answer (score 1):

That 1.3W figure is in the absolute maximum ratings section. DO NOT USE THAT SECTION FOR DESIGN!

You did not state the current involved. The SOA graph from the datasheet gives an indication: [image]

BTW did you notice that the first page states "RDSon=0.05" and "1.8V gate rated", but this is not true in combination!

[image]

As you mention a TL431 I guess you are using the FET as linear element? Bad idea IMO for such a tiny package, but at 100C/W (but check note 3 on p 2!), 50C ambient, and a maximum junction temperature of 150C (fig. 10) it should be able to do 1W continuously. But this is really the limit, and I doubt you can guarantee 50C ambient, so I would not be comfortable with this in a real design.

Comment: The MOSFET will work both in linear and saturation, as it regulates 3V from a input that ranges from 12V to 3V (battery or trafo). The max current is 100mA. The lowest Vgs will be ~ -2.5V, so 85mOhms should be fine at 100mA with a drop of only 8.5mV.